# Why do I need to run this script twice to delete all duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I do is create a temp table called Rent2 to deposit all duplicate modules my clients have registered, then I do a delete inner join statement before deleting the temp table.

But there is always a left over duplicate after this is done. What am I doing wrong here?

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblRent2` (
  `IdRent` INT(11) NOT NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO tblRent2 (SELECT IdRent FROM tblRent WHERE IdModule = 1 GROUP BY IdClient HAVING COUNT(IdModule) > 1);
INSERT INTO tblRent2 (SELECT IdRent FROM tblRent WHERE IdModule = 2 GROUP BY IdClient HAVING COUNT(IdModule) > 1);
INSERT INTO tblRent2 (SELECT IdRent FROM tblRent WHERE IdModule = 3 GROUP BY IdClient HAVING COUNT(IdModule) > 1);
INSERT INTO tblRent2 (SELECT IdRent FROM tblRent WHERE IdModule = 4 GROUP BY IdClient HAVING COUNT(IdModule) > 1);
INSERT INTO tblRent2 (SELECT IdRent FROM tblRent WHERE IdModule = 5 GROUP BY IdClient HAVING COUNT(IdModule) > 1);
INSERT INTO tblRent2 (SELECT IdRent FROM tblRent WHERE IdModule = 6 GROUP BY IdClient HAVING COUNT(IdModule) > 1);
INSERT INTO tblRent2 (SELECT IdRent FROM tblRent WHERE IdModule = 999 GROUP BY IdClient HAVING COUNT(IdModule) > 1);

DELETE r.* FROM tblRent r INNER JOIN tblRent2 r2 ON 
r.idRent = r2.idRent;

SELECT * FROM tblRent2;

DROP TABLE tblRent2;
```

The Original table looks like this:

```
IdRent | IDClient  | IdModule
1      |  30       |   999
2      |  30       |   999
3      |  31       |   1
4      |  31       |   1
```

Those are all primary keys.

Comment: Those are not *primary* keys, they are *foreign* keys (primary keys of *other* tables). Nevertheless, in the case of duplicate idrent, which rows do you want to delete?

Comment: I know they look like foreign keys, but the uses them as primary, the other tables exist but are not referenced as foreign. (something that we want to correct with this fix).

Comment: The duplicates I want to delete are the IdModule duplicates, after the fix repeated idClients can exist as long as there are different modules references between them.

Comment: So you want to delete duplicate idclient/idmodule combinations?

Comment: Yes, but hang on. I just noticed my problem is that I have triplicates in my table while my HAVING clause only detects the first duplicate registry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better question is why are you using a temporary table?

Just join the table to itself:

```
DELETE r2
FROM tblRent r
JOIN tblRent r2
    ON r.IDClient = r2.IDClient
    AND r.IdModule = r2.IdModule
    AND r.idRent < r2.idRent
```

This will clean up triplicates too, always leaving the row with the lowest `idRent`.

A key point (pardon the pun) is the extra join condition `r.idRent < r2.idRent`, which prevents rows from joining to themselves (by having unequal ids), and selects the last added row for deletion (by forcing one id to be less than the other). Using `r.idRent != r2.idRent` would cause *both* duplicates to be deleted.

Comment: I edited my question with more information about my original table.

Comment: See edited answer to deal with the new info in your question. Note that this handles duplicates, triplicates, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think your delete query is flawed.  Delete shouldn't require an asterist after the delete keyword.  You could use this query.

```
DELETE FROM tblRent WHERE idRent in (SELECT IdRent FROM tblRent2);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll use this instead, but I still need to run the script twice to eliminate all duplicates.